# Able to list Bucket but cannot upload a file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Using ASW javascript SDK v2 (cannot use v3 for dependency reasons related to my project)
I am facing an error when trying to upload a file to an S3 bucket with the following JS code.

FYI :

1. I am able to do so in VScode command line through aws CLI
2. My profile is configured and I can list buckets with code

Here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

const fileName = '/Users/*****/****/*****-ui/**/***/****/BE-Commands/cmd.json';

const uploadFile = () => {
  fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     const params = {
         Bucket: 'bucket-test', // pass your bucket name
         Key: 'contacts.csv', // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
         Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
     };
     s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
         if (s3Err) throw s3Err
         console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
     });
  });
};

uploadFile();
```

Getting this error :

```
Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (***.1***.1.182:*****)
    at internalConnect (node:net:1084:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:465:18)
    at node:net:1290:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',
  errno: -64,
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '1****.254.169.254',
  port: 80,
  time: 2023-08-10T18:15:50.727Z,
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
    errno: -64,
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '**********',
    port: 80,
    time: 2023-08-10T18:15:50.722Z,
    originalError: {
      message: 'EC2 Metadata roleName request returned error',
      errno: -64,
      code: 'EHOSTDOWN',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '***.254.***.***',
      port: 80,
      time: 2023-08-10T18:15:50.722Z,
      originalError: {
        errno: -64,
        code: 'EHOSTDOWN',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '***.***.***.***',
        port: 80,
        message: 'connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (***.***.1.***:49426)'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Run `aws configure list` in the working and failing environment. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be related to the fact that I am running it in a browser so the code did not work. I have simply added the code in an external JS code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Well, the SDK for AWS is detecting your environment. So the reason that you're not able to upload your file is because your configurations are not correct/not being detected. Ensure, that you are passing your configuration credentials correctly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

EDIT: Updated Documentation for SDK v2 since OP is using it